# Use ApiGateway Authorizer to Validate Github Payload Signature (X-Hub-Signature)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I am currently working on a simple api to receive Github event payloads, and I want to validate that they are coming from the correct source. With this I am working to use the hmac signature in the requests header (generated by github using a secret provided by me). To validate the signature, the ApiGateway authorizer requires the signature (X-Hub-Signature), the secret used to generate the signature, and the body of the message. As far as I can tell, Api Gateway does not allow you to pass the body to an ApiGateway Authorizer. Does anyone know a way around this that does not require additional proxy lambdas and s3?

*Note: The requester is the Github Webhook service (not able to add body to header)

Basic ApiGateway Auth Docs: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

Comment: tyler as far as i know a complete request object is made available whenever you recieve a request. including headers, paths, query strings, stage variables, or context variables request parameters. **Try log the request you would hopefully find your answer**.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it.

Pass your content to **Authorization** header of your incoming request, It will get delivered to your custom Authorizer.

Grab the contents of the from the below attribute,

> event.authorizationToken

where **event** is one of the parameters (1st) passed to lambda,

I currently encrypt and add all the info to that header and gets delivered to the Custom Authorizer lambda.

You can also access additional parameters as below in your custom Authorizer lambda:

```
var headers = event.headers;
var queryStringParameters = event.queryStringParameters;
var pathParameters = event.pathParameters;
var stageVariables = event.stageVariables;
var requestContext = event.requestContext;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know if I miss-understand this, but the issue I am having is that the request is generated by Github and are set to my endpoint (Github webhook). With that the header is not format-able for me (unless I want to make a large, and ugly re-template in my swagger api cloudformation file). Is this what you are referencing? Sorry for not having this in the question (updated it).

Comment: If will send the whole request to your Authorizer, if you notice the later part of the answer, you can log all the details that is coming from the incoming request and validate them and send 'Access' or 'Denied' based on the request contents.